# finding the sum of elements in a row and putting them in a column vector

Tags: matlab, plot

```
M = round(csvread('noob.csv'))

save projectDAT.dat M -ascii
load projectDAT.dat


mat = (projectDAT)
rowws(mat)
```

This is my main script. I have a excel file, which opens up a 20 x 20 matrix in matlab. Now I have to call a function in this mainscript, which would find the sum of elements in a row for me and put them in a column vector. Here is my function:

```
function sumRow = sum_of_rows(mat)
[m n] = size(mat);

sumRow = zeros(m,1);
for i = 1:m;
    for j = 1:n;
        sumRow(i) = sumRow(i) + mat(i,j);
    end
end
vec = sumRow;
end
```

I am required to plot a line graph using this column vector. I am supposed to call a function from the mainscript. The function should be able to take the input from this sum_of_rows function. I tried doing this:

```
function plotthegraph(~)

% Application for plotting the height of students
choice = menu('Choose the type of graph', 'Plot the data using a line plot',     'Plot the data using a bar plot');
if choice == 1
   plot_line(sum_of_rows) 
y = sum_of_rows
x = 1:length(y)
plot(x,y)
title('Bar graph')
xlabel('Number of characters')
ylabel('Number of grades')

elseif choice == 2
   plot_bar(sum_of_columns)
end
```

Its not working out though. Can someone please help me out, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you.

Comment: The function rowws has to be in a file called `rowws.m` on the Matlab search path (which includes the current dir). Also - you perhaps know already, but the built-in function `sum()` does what your script does.

Comment: `rowws` function may not be in the MATLAB serach path. Save it in the same directory as your main script. Additionally, you don't need a `for-loop`. Just do `sumRow=sum(mat,2)`

Comment: Yeah, but my instructor wants us to use the for loop. it sucks

Comment: I was saving it in the wrong folder. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Hey could you help me out with one more thing. I edited the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the builtin sum function? I think

`mysum = sum(mat,2)`

would do the trick.

Comment: Looks like @Parag beat me to it.